# Build Xcode Project and retrieve .app file?

Tags: ios, macos, build

Ok, pretty weird request, but how can I build a Xcode Project on my server and retrieve the .app file? I would like to do this using iOS and Mac OS X. These process is referred to as a Build Server sometimes. But iOS is most crucial. Also I'd imagine there some other technologies involved in this process. So Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with reading about Hudson:

http://hudson-ci.org/

and

http://blogs.globallogic.com/build-management-for-ios-and-mac-based-projects